# VS Code dart widget wrapper not working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

As you see below, VS Code autocompletion in wrapping widgets suddenly changed behavior and it doesn't merge widget arguments with the child and I should delete extra parentheses manually.
Also, I saw this problem on function autocompletes too.
Anybody can help?

[image]

[image]